# Remove link from product attributes in tab "additional information"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tabs

Since some updates of WooCommerce, Wordpress, Theme etc. on our product pages in the product-tab "additional information" some attributes are now linkable (to some automatic created pages). I cant find the setting how to disable it and even so no php solution for functions.php. I neither want that automatic pages then the links.

[image]

Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find a real Solution, but I used CSS to visually hide the link, but actually the link still exists, but its not clickable anymore. Note: change this CSS to your font-color:

```
.shop_attributes a[rel="tag"] {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: #888;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is archive deactivation for the attributes.

- Go to Attributes
- Select and Edit the linkable Attribute
- Uncheck "Enable Archives"
- Update

Should do the trick.